Can the headphone jack of a laptop send MIDI signals with a Jack TRS cable?
I'm trying to add new controls to a loop pedal that has a 3.5 Midi TRS input jack.
The pedal is the BOSS RC-500 and has all the necessary features to handle incoming MIDI signals.
I would like to know if a basic headphone jack (normally used for music and mic) on a laptop could send this kind of MIDI commands through a Jack 3.5 Male-Male TRS cable (for example the BOSS BCC-2-3535), or is this impossible ?
My main idea would be to program something simple on my PC to send the MIDI commands and not having to buy a MIDI controller.
Thanks in advance

No.
In addition to the 31.25 kilobaud rate, the MIDI protocol requires 5V signal level and 5V reference voltage (EDIT: Later revision to spec allows 3.3V for both). Audio outputs typically don't output DC at all, AC components can't be adjusted to a specific voltage and for headphones the maximum voltage is somewhere around 1V.
USB/MIDI interfaces and DIN to TRS adapters don't cost much. Just get one.

Nitpick: note that midi requires a current, not a voltage (which is why it can work on 3.3v). But I completely agree that, basically, the electronic is really not made for that kind of signals..

Thank you for the clear answer! Do I need to get a specific DIN adapter? It seems that there are 2 conventions for that type of connector

@Tom if you read the specs from https://midi.org/midi-1-0-core-specifications it's pretty explicit about 5V. The protocol has loose enough tolerances that I'm not surprised that 3.3V would usually work but the spec really says 5V.

@ElevenJune yes, you do need to either look up which adapter you need or buy both and try them out.

@ojs I'm basing myself on the update of 2014, which says: "The MIDI circuit is a 5mA current loop" (beginning of midi circuit paragraph). Note that I fundamentally agreeing with you ;), just nitpicking. The old spec was based on voltage, as per nearly only 5v circuits were in there. We now more refer to the current that needs to go through the optocoupler, and base the calculations on that.

@Tom I have the feeling I'm doing your homework here, but look what it says right before the part about 5mA current loop, and then look at the picture the text refers.

@ojs in the revision of 2014, the same schematic refers to "Vtx" and not "5V" anymore. And gives components values for the most used standards, 3.3 and 5v.

In preambule: "This document updates the midi 1.0 electrical specification to include 3.3 v signalling and optional RF grounding. This document replaces the hardware section of the midi 1.0 detailed specifications which is included in the MMA publication "the complete Midi 1.0 detailed specification". Can't find an open link to that update though

@Tom aren't references that aren't available the best references? There are references to 3.3V on midi.org if you dig around a bit. In any case, isn't the current a result of voltage difference between signal and Vtx, the resistor at receiving side and voltage drop in the optocoupler so it's a bit of stretch to say it's always 5mA?

https://www.midi.org/wp-content/uploads/wpforo/default_attachments/1709416667-ca33-MIDI-10-Electrical-Specification-Update.pdf

To be fair, that was only a nitpicking comment on an answer I already found nice and which is coming from the midi spec I'm basing my designs from. I'm not sure it is worth a big debate, especially with a condescending tone. At least, I won't lose sleep on that ;)

@Tom thank you :) I feel like this is unnecessary nitpicking too, but the suggestion that the signal current is there without voltage made me feel like nitpicking too. In any case, the confusing part in the spec is that current flows between signal and Vtx and ground is there just for shielding and rest of the spec talks about current on / off instead of voltage levels.

Never heard of someone attempting that. The jack port on a computer is made to output audio, ie AC signal analogue, it is hard to know how it will coop with digital signals. It is especially true as Midi is sent at 31.250kbaud, a frequency which is normally cutout by audio interfaces as it is beyond the hearing range.
You could get away cheaply with a usb/midi interface alongside a din/trs adapter (beware, there are two standards...)

Thank you for your answer ! I least I know that just buying a capable will not do it. Do you know if an audio interface like this one (that I already own) could do the job, or would it be the same result ? https://focusrite.com/products/scarlett-2i2-3rd-gen

That Focusrite model doesn't have MIDI. Many other audio interfaces do, but for some reason Focusrite doesn't include it in their cheaper models.

Thank you ! I found this : https://snapbeat.net/usb-midi-trs-interface/ . This should do it ?
